# Не работает маршрутизация на линуксе (ubunta 18.04) между двумя компьютерами через третий ( маршрутизатор )

Tags: linux, сеть, маршрутизация

задача: Соединить три компьютера (hostA, hostB, hostC) по сети так, чтобы hostC маршрутизировал трафик между hostA и hostB.

Результат:
A <-------------------> C <----------------->   B
192.168.0.1        (192.168.0.2; 192.168.1.2)       192.168.1.1
Linux Ubuntu 18.04 три виртуальные машины.
Необходимо, чтобы с машины A работал ping 192.168.1.1 и наоборот с машины B ping A. Все должно быть через машину C. На данный момент пингуются обе машины с машины C, а между друг другом не пингуются. Ip forwarding включен. Пытался включить проброс с одного интерфейса на другой на машине

```
C:sudo ip route add 192.168.0.2 via 192.168.1.2
```

и наооборот

```
C: sudo ip route add 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.0.2
```

на машине A включал дефолтный маршрут

```
sudo ip route default via 192.168.0.2
```

и на машине B

```
sudo ip route default via 192.168.1.2
```

Пиг с машины А на B не проходит

комп C

пути

```
C:$ ip r
default via 192.168.43.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.43.136 metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s9 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.43.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.136 
192.168.43.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.43.136 metric 100
```

адреса ( средняя машина )

```
C: $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:53:9a:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.136/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 2818sec preferred_lft 2818sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe53:9a87/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:43:1c:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe43:1c39/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f7:22:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s9
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef7:22c0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

вывод форвардинга

```
C: ~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Комп A ( первый )

```
 A $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:80:23:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.241/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 2480sec preferred_lft 2480sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe80:2303/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:90:0c:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe90:cea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

маршруты

```
A: $ ip r
default via 192.168.0.2 dev enp0s8 onlink 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.43.241 metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.43.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.241 
192.168.43.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.43.241 metric 100
```

Комп B

```
B: ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:5b:24:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.221/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 2404sec preferred_lft 2404sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe5b:2412/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:60:c6:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe60:c67b/64 scope link
```

маршруты

```
B: $ ip r 
default via 192.168.0.2 dev enp0s8 onlink 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.43.241 metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.43.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.241 
192.168.43.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.43.241 metric 100
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Очень мало информации. Какая ОС хотя бы? Если "не работает", значит вы что-то уже пытались сделать?

Comment: исправил ос линукс убунта

Comment: Форвард не включён по-моему , sysctl что пишет?

Comment: вывод `ip a` и `ip r` со всех трёх машин в студию... ну и `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` с той что в центре до кучи... а ещё как именно на уровне виртуальных машин ты организовал их в подсети?

Comment: добавил информацию о адресах и маршрутах

Comment: @AlexGlebe - маска норм

Comment: на компе В маршрут должен быть `default via 192.168.1.2 dev enp0s8 onlink ` у Вас шлюж не тот

Comment: не хватает маршрутов до противоположных подсетей на `A` и `B`. на `A` нужно сделать `ip r add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.2`. На `B`: `ip r add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.2`... или, в качестве альтернативы, можно сделать `С` шлюзом по умолчанию в обеих подсетях...

Comment: всем спасибо, сделал дефолтный маршрут на A и B, на C ничего не настраивал все заработало

Comment: @AlexGlebe вы заблуждаетесь в обоих своих комментариях.